# Compiling the IPCV for Scilab 2024 (Mac Intel 64 bit)

Tags: gcc, clang, scilab

I have a 64 bit Mac on Intel. I am trying to install the IPCV (Image Processing and Computer Vision) toolbox for Scilab 2024.

I have the XCode installed and I have run the `xcode-select` command for agreeing to the license and all other instructions which are available on the Internet.

When I initiate the installation I have the following set of error messages after all the initial verbose text:

```
Building gateway...
   Generate a gateway file
   Generate a loader file
   Generate a Makefile
   ilib_gen_Make: configure : Generate Makefile.
Detection of C/C++/Fortran Compilers 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c 
checking whether build environment is sane... yes 
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d 
checking for gawk... no 
checking for mawk... no 
checking for nawk... no 
checking for awk... awk 
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes 
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes 
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no 
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin23.0.0 
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin23.0.0 
checking how to print strings... printf 
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style) 
checking for gcc... gcc 
checking whether the C compiler works... no 
atomsInstall: Error while building the toolbox '/Applications/scilab-2024.0.0.app/Contents/share/scilab/contrib/IPCV/4.1.2'
```

I am wondering that inspite of the GCC being installed on `homebrew` and the XCode being installed, the C compilation is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that in the file `sci_gateway/cpp/builder_gateway_cpp.sce` you change the line

```
inter_cflags = ' -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -I'+OPENCV_INCLUDE;
```

by

```
inter_cflags = OPENCV_INCLUDE;
```

New official builds of IPCV for Intel and arm64 will be available this week.